# How can I prevent Windows from using Intel's IGD

Tags: drivers, cpu, intel-graphics

###### intro

I have a 10850K CPU though my motherboard does not support IGD display and thus, I use a discrete graphics. Still, I believe that the OS' (ie. Windows) drivers may still use the integrated graphics device of the processor to render something (ie. hardware acceleration) even though the results are going to be displayed using the discrete graphics.

###### the question at hand

Now, is it somehow possible to prevent Windows from doing that? Think of it as I'd like to forcefully make 10850K a KF version.

###### in before calling it the X/Y problem

I have an issue that from time to time my PC freezes to a point that the hard reset button doesn't work. It happens only on Windows (I also have macOS and Linux on that PC) and only when I'm using desktop env (ie. never in a video game). Thus, I believe that Windows' CPU drivers make use of the integrated graphics to process *some stuff ™*, which neither macOS nor Linux do, while in video game the iGPU is idle due to everything being a 3D render that's handled by the dGPU. I'd like the drivers not to use anything from the iGPU-package to see whether this will fix the issue.

Comment: If your motherboard doesn’t support IGD (I assume you mean iGPU and the fact it doesn’t have DisplayPort or HDMI) then it’s impossible for you to use the iGPU.  The simplest way to avoid using the iGPU is to uninstall Intel’s display drivers and only install the Nvidia or AMD display drivers

Comment: Does Windows even detect the iGPU (in Device Manager)? Are Intel graphics drivers even installed?

Comment: Your computer is freezing from time to time and you assume it's the integrated GPU that your system doesn't use, but you give no evidence supporting your assumption, and we're loth to take your word on this. Please edit your question to add further information, evidence to support your assertion.